# "No rvm rubies installed yet." despite Ruby being already installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

Having issues about Ruby environment setting.
Although both RVM and Ruby are installed, when command "rvm list" is run, it shows error message, "# No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install". Why does it happen, and how can it be fixed?

````
$ rvm list

# No rvm rubies installed yet. Try 'rvm help install'.

$ rvm -v
rvm 1.29.12 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.6.8p205 (2021-07-07 revision 67951) [universal.x86_64-darwin21]
$ ```
````

Comment: Run `which ruby` to figure out where this executable is coming from. It could be your system Ruby, which is not the same as an RVM-installed binary.

Comment: Thanks @Casper for the comment. Running v```which ruby``` and received response ```/usr/bin/ruby```. so This means this is my system Ruby and not RVM-installed binary?

Comment: Yes exactly. `rvm list` only lists RVM-installed Rubies. So when it tells you nothing is installed yet, it is correct. Go ahead and install any version you like. I think it should work even with the system Ruby present.

Comment: @Casper now I installed ruby-2.6.8 and it can be managed by RVM. The subject issue's resolved! Thank you. But another issue is coming up. The terminal says rails is not installed when running "rails" command. Does it happen for the same reason? my system and binary one...

Comment: ```Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

$ sudo gem install rails
Successfully installed rails-7.0.1
Parsing documentation for rails-7.0.1
Done installing documentation for rails after 0 seconds
1 gem installed
$ rails new DevcampPortfolio -T --database=postgresql
Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:

    $ sudo gem install rails

You can then rerun your "rails" command.```

Comment: The above is the terminal response when running "rails" command.

Comment: The second issue was resolved. The path to install rails and the path of hash were different, which were why I kept receiving "Rails is not installed" message. I deleted hash path and that solved the issue. Thanks.